# Facebook API function stalls when missing data

Tags: javascript, json, facebook-graph-api, if-statement

We are currently making an 'app' in school that's supposed to return facebook info from me/likes with the facebook API. It does however stall as soon as a given like (page) does not have the required info. If it has no cover photo, our function stalls. We are quite new to this, and cant work out an if statement. Maybe someone can help? :-)

---

function getData() {

```
FB.api('/me/likes?fields=name,created_time,cover&limit=999', 
        function(response){

    var jsondata = response.data;

    for (PROTO in jsondata) {
        console.log(jsondata[PROTO].name, jsondata[PROTO].created_time, jsondata[PROTO].cover_picture);

        var table = $('#table').get(0); 

        var row = table.insertRow(-1); 

        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0); 
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1); 
        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2); 

        cell1.innerHTML = jsondata[PROTO].name
        cell2.innerHTML = jsondata[PROTO].created_time
        cell3.innerHTML = "<img src='"+jsondata[PROTO].cover.picture+"' />"


    }
});
```

Comment: Are you requiring the `user_likes` permission?  You're also not handling if an error occurs.

Comment: `jsondata[PROTO].cover_picture` or `jsondata[PROTO].cover.picture` which is it?

Comment: Hey Guys, thank you very much for replying. There was a problem with the for (PROTO in jsondata) - by naming that with capital letters it thought that it was the prototype which was also named PROTO. It sorted it self out :)